# Diferencia writeUnshared y writeObject

Tags: java, poo

Quisiera saber, si es posible mediante un ejemplo, cual es en sí la diferencia entre los métodos de la clase `ObjectOutputStream`, `writeObject` y `writeUnshared`. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos, lo primero que se debe hacer es ***[leer la documentación!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object))***.

Copiado literalmente de la documentación de java para `writeUnshared`():

> Writes an "unshared" object to the ObjectOutputStream. **This method is identical to writeObject**, except that it always writes the given object as a new, unique object in the stream (as opposed to a back-reference pointing to a previously serialized instance). Specifically:
> An object written via writeUnshared is always serialized in the same manner as a newly appearing object (an object that has not been written to the stream yet), regardless of whether or not the object has been written previously.
> If writeObject is used to write an object that has been previously written with writeUnshared, the previous writeUnshared operation is treated as if it were a write of a separate object. In other words, ObjectOutputStream will never generate back-references to object data written by calls to writeUnshared.
> While writing an object via writeUnshared does not in itself guarantee a unique reference to the object when it is deserialized, it allows a single object to be defined multiple times in a stream, so that multiple calls to readUnshared by the receiver will not conflict. Note that the rules described above only apply to the base-level object written with writeUnshared, and not to any transitively referenced sub-objects in the object graph to be serialized.

Tal como dice, `writeUnshared` es idéntico a `writeObject` excepto que siempre escribe el objeto como un objeto **NUEVO** en vez del objeto referenciado. Es decir, puedes enviar 3 veces el "mismo" objeto por el stream, y las 3 veces será un "objeto nuevo" a la salida de dicho stream.

---

Para información con más detalle, te recomiendo leer la documentación con calma. (Y si no se te da bien el inglés, nunca es tarde para empezar! En programación te vas a hartar de leer en inglés, puesto que la mayoría de la información detallada se encuentra en dicho idioma).